# HTML scraping in VBA - all values in multipage list

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to gather all of the property data from this website:
http://taxsales.lgbs.com/

There are currently 7,000+ properties, but on any given view of the page I can only see 15 - 20 depending on screen resolution.

I have figured out, roughly, how to search through the HTML for the property names and details. Because the initial search has a warning screen, I'm using the following code to "click" the "Agree" button to see the subsequent search page. You can also see that I don't know how to find only the property details, and am instead taking (basically) all of the HTML from the whole site and sifting through it later in excel.

Questions:

1) Is there any way to see data for all of the properties at once? -or- How can I "page" through each portion of the results to eventually collect all of them?

2) How can I collect only the data for property address, sale date, sale type, etc.?

```
Sub HTML_scrape()

Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim objCollection2 As Object
Dim r As Integer
Dim v As Object




' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

' Using the URL with "full" map
IE.navigate "http://taxsales.lgbs.com/map?lat=39.576604&lon=-96.72178200000002&zoom=4&offset=0&ordering=sale_date,address_full,uid&sale_type=SALE,RESALE,STRUCK%20OFF,FUTURE%20SALE&in_bbox=-137.2217809271164,15.247775193567845,-56.221783072883625,57.63696077532424"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4)
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
Loop

' Click the Agree Button
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")
objCollection(0).Click

Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4)
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
Loop

' Find all tags and collect the associated data
' This should only find the relevant property data, but I can not
' figure out how to only take the information within a
' <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="listing.addressClick()"> tag
Set objCollection2 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("*")
r = 1
For Each v In objCollection2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Value = v.outerHTML
    r = r + 1
Next

With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
    Dim DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    .Replace What:="@", Replacement:="'"
    .Replace What:=DQ, Replacement:="'"
End With


End Sub
```

Property Sale Date HTML:

```
<li ng-if="listing.property.sale_date" class="ng-binding ng-scope"><label>Sale Date:</label> 4/5/18 9:00 AM</li>
```

Property Address HTML:

```
<a ng-click="listing.addressClick()" class="ng-binding"> 02863 Stouton St, Philadelphia PA 19134-3515 </a>
```

Next Button HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" class="ng-binding">Next</a>
```

Comment: I keep getting The requested URL could not be retrieved

Comment: @QHarr Not sure why that would be - it just copied and pasted the code into VBA in excel and it seemed to run ok (?)

Comment: Your provided link within the scraper is inaccessible.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what the problem could be. When I use the script it works fine on my machine, and when I copy/paste the URL in the VBA code it also renders a website in firefox, chrome, and IE without issue.I don't have any special permissions that you all wouldn't be privy to.

Comment: Has it worked for you today?

Comment: Yes, just ran it and seemed to work fine

Comment: Same here, can't access that website

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky approach to use web requests (xhr) instead. Looking at the requests for the page it looks like it returns a JSON object. I'm parsing this JSON object and dumping it to a range on the first sheet. Here's some code that should get you started.

```
'You'll need the following references:
'MSXML v6.0
'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'JSON project from: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Public Sub Scraper()
    Dim webrequest      As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim JSON            As Object
    Dim responses       As Object
    Dim itemdict        As Variant
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim k               As Long
    Dim item            As Variant
    Dim myarray         As Variant: ReDim myarray(0 To 20, 0 To 5000)
    Dim url             As String: url = "http://taxsales.lgbs.com/api/property_sales/?in_bbox=-139.04111793750002%2C7.97834134877145%2C-54.40244606250002%2C61.39968867373271&offset=10&ordering=sale_date%2Caddress_full%2Cuid&sale_type=SALE%2CRESALE%2CSTRUCK+OFF%2CFUTURE+SALE"

    For i = 0 To 10 'Do a loop to get SOME of the data, probably need a different loop here
        With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
            .Open "GET", url
            .setRequestHeader "accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
            .send

            'Parse the response into a JSON dict
            Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            url = JSON("next") ' the next URl to send a GET request
            Set responses = JSON("results") 'Get the results Dict

            On Error Resume Next ' getting an error, just ignoring for now

            For Each itemdict In responses
                j = 0

                'add headers
                If k = 0 Then
                    For Each item In itemdict
                        myarray(j, k) = item
                        j = j + 1
                    Next
                End If

                'add values
                For Each item In itemdict
                    myarray(j, k) = itemdict(item)
                    j = j + 1
                Next

                k = k + 1
            Next

            On Error GoTo 0

        End With
    Next

    ReDim Preserve myarray(0 To 20, 0 To k - 1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:T" & k - 1).Value = TransposeArray(myarray)

End Sub

'using this function as worksheetfunction.transpose causing issues
Public Function TransposeArray(myarray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim Xupper As Long
    Dim Yupper As Long
    Dim tempArray As Variant

    Xupper = UBound(myarray, 2)
    Yupper = UBound(myarray, 1)

    ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)

    For X = 0 To Xupper
        For Y = 0 To Yupper
            tempArray(X, Y) = myarray(Y, X)
        Next
    Next

    TransposeArray = tempArray
End Function
```

Output:

[image: Example]